# GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:17:18.242: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I'm in Ubuntu 20.04 using Opencv 4.4.0 in C++. I can run the file but failure throwing the next message:

[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv-4.4.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (713) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: error de sintaxis
[ WARN:0] global /home/user/opencv-4.4.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created

Error opening video stream or file

I don't know what's the problem

Comment: the message looks clear: you provided an invalid url (aka: path to file).

Comment: Why is this critical? When is the project due (GMT)?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews "critical" is a word used by gstreamer. this isn't one of those "fix my homework by midnight" questions.

Comment: You'll have to add context from where the error is coming from. Not every error with gstreamer is an issue even the critical ones.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.